# Controlador con dos metodos post en un web api

Tags: c#, webservice, asp.net-web-api

Estoy haciendo un servicio web api con c#. En un controlador necesito tener dos métodos post.

Ahora mismo, tengo algo parecido a esto.

```html
 public class TramitesController : ApiController
    {
    [ResponseType(typeof(Tramite))]
    [BasicAuthenticationFilter]
    public IHttpActionResult PostTramite(Tramite tramite)
      {
      return null;
   }
   
    [ResponseType(typeof(Incidencia))]
    [BasicAuthenticationFilter]
    public IHttpActionResult PostTramite(Incidencia incidencia)
      {
      return null;
      }
    }
```

si comento uno u otro método, funciona correctamente, pero los dos a la vez no, da error.

Es posible tener mas de un método post?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías darle una ruta diferente, bien moviendo una de las acciones a un nuevo controlador, bien indicándole una ruta diferente a través de una atributo `RouteAttribute`:

```
public class TramitesController : ApiController
{
[ResponseType(typeof(Tramite))]
[BasicAuthenticationFilter]
public IHttpActionResult PostTramite(Tramite tramite)
  {
  return null;
  }

[ResponseType(typeof(Incidencia))]
[BasicAuthenticationFilter]
[Route("Incidencia")]
public IHttpActionResult PostTramite(Incidencia incidencia)
  {
  return null;
  }
}
```

De esta forma la primera acción tendría la ruta por defecto del controlador (si has dejado la configuración de rutas por defecto sería `http://rutaAplicacion/api/Tramites`) y la segunda añadiendo a la ruta `Incidencia` (`http://rutaAplicacion/api/Tramites/Incidencia`).

Comment: No lo he probado pero no seria `[Route("api/tramites/incidencia")]`?

Comment: No, la ruta especificada en el atributo es relativa a la del controlador

Comment: La solución es como dice @Einer con [Route("api/tramites/incidencia")] (o al menos a mi me ha funcionado). Gracias de todas las formas a los dos

Comment: Efectivamente la solución es decorando con atributos en los métodos (aunque recomendaría cambiar el nombre del método por PostIncidencia), acuerdate de agregar MapHttpAttributeRoutes para que tome estos atributos, y puedes utilizar RoutePrefix en el controlador para definir la url base de todos los demas metodos (asi no estas repitiendo "api/tramites...").  Para mas info de [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)